# FragmentManager can't find view in inflated view

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentmanager

I have an inflated layout that I add in the window manager.

```
void createFloatView()
{
    final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getApplication().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

    _myView = (RelativeLayout) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

    wm.addView(_myView, params);
}
```

This layout contains a FrameLayout that I want to put contents in, but the fragmentManager can't seem to find the view id (R.id.container) which is present on the layout (R.layout.popup).

```
void replaceFragment()
{
    FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, customFragment).commit();
}
```

It says 'No view found for id' which points to the R.id.container

Here is the popup layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I found other solutions saying that I should use a getChildFragmentManager() but I can't seem to figure out where to put this, as it is saying that I cannot put it in a static context?

So how can I let the fragment manager access this id?

Comment: Show your layout file

Comment: Good luck...  FragmentManager instance is inside your Activity...  This view not...

Comment: Declare container in your layout.

Comment: @AnandSingh it is present in the layout file

Comment: Obviously it is not possible (Fragments especially support Fragments in the View added directly to WindowManager)